# Does any one know about this error: "Wrong Local header signature: 0x6D74683C"?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, download, windows-phone-8, webrequest

The following code is used to download a zip file and unzip it on phone.

The same code used to work on WP7, I started tested on WP8 device, and strange thing is happening... now **it works on WP8 but *NOT* on WP7** anymore.

On the WP7 it gives an **ERROR**:

```
Wrong Local header signature: 0x6D74683C
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong here?

**THE OBSERVATION (2 days after posting the question)**

I have some observations.... Sharing here in detail ([Image format](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8xOhdKHzbkyMjlqTm94dXNaWDg/edit?usp=sharing)) or ([Excel format](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8xOhdKHzbkyeENJbTMwUG0wODQ/edit?usp=sharing))

**THE CODE**

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Net;

namespace iq_main.Network
{

    public class IQ_Download
    {
        private string zipFilePassword = String.Empty;
        private string fileNameToBeStoredAs = String.Empty;
        private string urlToBeDownloaded = String.Empty;
        private HttpWebResponse response;

        public void Download(string _urlToBeDownloaded = GlobalConstants.DownloadLanguageConfigurationUrl, string _fileNameToBeStoredAs = GlobalConstants.DownloadLanguageConfigurationXmlFilename, string _zipFilePassword = GlobalConstants.DownloadZipsPassword)
        {

            urlToBeDownloaded = _urlToBeDownloaded; 
            fileNameToBeStoredAs = _fileNameToBeStoredAs;
            zipFilePassword = _zipFilePassword;

            System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(urlToBeDownloaded);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);

            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebRequestCallBack), request);
        }


        void WebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest resultInfo = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)resultInfo.EndGetResponse(result);
            try
            {

                using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    //open isolated storage to save files
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(httpwebStreamReader.BaseStream))
                        {
                            if (zipFilePassword != String.Empty)
                                s.Password = zipFilePassword;//if archive is encrypted

                            ZipEntry theEntry;
                            try
                            {
//EXCEPTION OCCURS ON THE VERY NEXT LINE (while...)    
                                while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                                {
                                    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theEntry.Name);
                                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);
                                    fileName = fileNameToBeStoredAs;

                                    // create directory
                                    if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        isoStore.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                                        //Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                                    }

                                    if (fileName != String.Empty)
                                    {

                                        //save file to isolated storage
                                        using (BinaryWriter streamWriter =
                                                new BinaryWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(theEntry.Name,
                                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, isoStore)))
                                        {

                                            int size = 2048;
                                            byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                                            while (true)
                                            {
                                                size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                                                if (size > 0)
                                                    streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                                                else
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (ZipException ze)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(ze.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }//WebRequestCallBack Method */
    } //Class ends
}
```

THE OUTPUT STACK

```
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'string.operator !='
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.Password.set'
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'string.operator !='
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.Password.set'
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry'
    A first chance exception of type 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException' occurred in SharpZipLib.WindowsPhone7.dll
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Exception.Message.get'
    Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine'
    Wrong Local header signature: 0x6D74683C
    A first chance exception of type 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException' occurred in SharpZipLib.WindowsPhone7.dll
    Wrong Local header signature: 0x6D74683C
```

Comment: could you post the whole exception stack, because I think the error has something todo with zip file. Does your exception start with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException?

Comment: I created zip with WINRAR-64 and WINRAR-32 bit. It didn't help

Comment: which version of SharpZipLib are you using?

Comment: I recommend opening a question on http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/12.aspx because this sounds like a bug in the library to me. You could also try to update your version of SharpZibLib.

Comment: which is the latest version? If you know any newer version, please let me know where can I download it from? I couldn't find any newer version than this. - Thank you MUG4N!

Comment: Okay, i have some observations.... Sharing here in detail (Image format https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8xOhdKHzbkyMjlqTm94dXNaWDg/edit?usp=sharing) or (Excel format https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8xOhdKHzbkyeENJbTMwUG0wODQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The header code 0x6D74683C corresponds to the ASCII sequence `<htm`, which I presume is the truncated HTML header in a web page. If you are downloading the content of the .zip archive, then perhaps it means the web server is returning HTML code instead of the intended archive (an error page or something like that). Maybe you should check the HTTP Content-Type header before feeding the stream to the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 4):

When you use WP7 you receive a html from dropbox:

> Found
>
> The resource was found at {"your new link here}; you should be
>   redirected automatically. 
>   ------------------------------------ WSGI Server

In Wp8 ithis redirect works automatically, but in Wp7 this redirect doesn't work.

I think the solution for you: just change link to new(you can find it in html file that you receive)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was same as "Leandro Taset" and "d.lavysh" explained in their answers. However, it's still unknown that why WP7 gets additions HTML headers?

Anyway, the modified code, which is **now working for both WP7 and WP8 devices. This code is also capable of downloading files either from a Web-Hosting service or from DropBox.**

The code I posted above is almost the same, I only modified the **`Download`** method, which, after modification, looks like this:

```
    public async void Download(string _urlToBeDownloaded = GlobalConstants.DownloadLanguageConfigurationUrl, string _fileNameToBeStoredAs = GlobalConstants.DownloadLanguageConfigurationXmlFilename, string _zipFilePassword = GlobalConstants.DownloadZipsPassword)
    {
        //The following IF block is addition to the code above. 
        //Here the headers are checked and if "WP7" and the URL is pointing to  the "Dropbox", the inner URL is fetched out of the headers.
        if (GlobalVariables.IsWP7 && _urlToBeDownloaded.ToLower().Contains("dropbox"))
        {

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_urlToBeDownloaded);
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;

            for (int i = 0; i < webResponse.Headers.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (webResponse.Headers.AllKeys[i].ToLower() == "location")
                {
                    _urlToBeDownloaded = webResponse.Headers["location"] ;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        urlToBeDownloaded = _urlToBeDownloaded ;
        fileNameToBeStoredAs = _fileNameToBeStoredAs;
        zipFilePassword = _zipFilePassword;


        System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(urlToBeDownloaded);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebRequestCallBack), request);
    }
```